# Expectation Of A Constant

Tags: probability

Question says that " Consider a constant random variable,i.e. a random variable with all its mass a constant $k$.This is discrete random variable with pmf $p(k)$" Then ,solves it ."Because $|k|$ is finite , we have by definition $E(k)=k p(k)=k$ "
But I am not able to understand how the did that without using any summation. 
$E(X)=\sum_{x}^{}x p(x)$ replacing $ X=k$ , we get
$E(k)=\sum k p(k)= \sum k *1$ Since $p(k)=1 $

$E(k)=\sum k. $ This makes it  a series of k with sum $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ .Please tell me where I went wrong .

Answer (score 3):

If $K$ is your random variable with values in $\Bbb N_0$ and such that $$p(K=n)=\begin{cases}1&n=k\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ then
$$ E[K]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty np(K=n)=0\cdot 0+1\cdot 0+\ldots +k\cdot 1+(k+1)\cdot 0+\ldots=k$$